# MVC - passing js variable to controller through ajax then using it in view

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

**script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        disabledDates: [
            new Date()
        ],
        inline: true,
        format: 'L',
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
        minDate: new Date(),
        useCurrent: false
    });

    $('#datetimepicker').on('change.datetimepicker', function (event) {
        var formatted_date = event.date.format('M/DD/YYYY');
        $('#datetimepickerOut').val(formatted_date);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Create")',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            data: { calendarDate: formatted_date },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#divTimeSlots').fadeIn("slow");
            },
            failure: function (result) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });

    });

    $('#divTimeSlots input').on('change', function (event) {
        $('#SlotTimeOut').val($("[type='radio']:checked").val());
    });
});
</script>
```

**controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create(string calendarDate)
{
    testViewModel mvm = new testViewModel();

    mvm.myDate = calendarDate;
}
```

**Create view:**

```
<div class="col-md-5" id="divTimeSlots" style="display: none;">
@{
    var getDate = Model.myDate;

    foreach (var rTimeSlots in Model.ListSlotTimeForRadio.Where(n =>
        n.BranchCode == "MNL1" &&
        n.Slots > 0
        &&
        n.SlotCode == getDate
        ))
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ListSlotTimeForRadio, rTimeSlots.SlotTime,
        new { htmlAttributes =
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "id", "timeSlots" },
                { "class", "form-control" }
            }
        })

        @rTimeSlots.SlotTime<br>
    }
}
</div>
```

as you can see in my script, that is inline datepicker. when i click on any date in the timepicker, the value will be pass on the variable formatted_date. formatted_date will also be pass on to controller through ajax (see calendarDate). then then calendarDate is passed to model as myDate (see controller). clicking on any date, the radiobutton will appear base on the foreach and .fadein("slow") in script. but, when i add the && n.SlotCode == getDate in foreach, the radiobutton list is not appearing. getDate is myDate.

when i use && n.SlotCode == "2/22/2019", that is working, radiobutton list is showing. but when i use == getDate, it doesn't work.

[image: debugged controller]
[image: debugged view]

as i'm debugging it, i'm getting the date correctly. but the radiobutton list is not appearing, i placed it in the success function. but it seems that it is not working correctly.

i don't know what's wrong. please help. tia

Comment: But did you debug to check if there is a matching value of `n.SlotCode` to `getDate`?

Comment: @SivaGopal yes, as i clicked the date, it is passing through the controller (as i'm debugging from controller to view) then to view getDate - is also the date that i clicked. the value is there

Comment: i updated the pictures

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parameter on your ajax call. Add

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        data: { calendarDate: formatted_date },
        success: function (data) {}
```

At the moment you're sending nothing to the controller

Comment: when i add type: 'POST'
i'm getting 500 internal server error, as i pressed f12 in my chrome browser. but without that. no error

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug your view code and see if below code return true:

.SlotCode == getDate

I am assuming that below conditions are true

n.BranchCode == "MNL1" &&
        n.Slots > 0

That is the only reason that you are not able to see the radio button.

Comment: yes, with .SlotCode == getDate, i'm getting the date i clicked. also the other conditions are met and correct.